# Floated <li>'s with seemingly all margin's set to "0," but still seeing space between siblings?

Tags: css, html-lists

So I'm creating an unordered list, floated to the right and styled with varying backgrounds to fashion a menu.

It was hell setting up the Jquery (animation queues, repeating animations while hovered, etc,) but I got it to work finally.  Here's the CSS and Jquery for the navigation, and animation.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#nav li").hover(function() {

            $(this).children('p').stop(true, true).animate({opacity: "show"}, "fast");

        }, function() {

            $(this).children('p').stop(true, true).animate({opacity: "hide"}, "fast");

        });

    });

</script>

#nav {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   background:#FF0000;
   clear:both;   
   float:right;   
  }  
#nav li {  
   position:relative;
   list-style:none;   
   padding-left:0;   
   margin-left:0;   
   float:right;   
   width:75px;   
  }  
#nav li a {   
   display:block;   
   width:75px;   
   height:48px;   
   margin-left:0;   
   padding-left:0;   
   Z-index:20;  
  }
.hover {   
   display:none;  
   position:absolute;  
   top:0;
   left:0;  
   height:48px;  
   width:75px;   
   z-index:0;   
  }  
.nav1 a {   
   background-image:url(images/nav_1.gif) 
  }  
.nav2 a {   
   background-image:url(images/nav_2.gif) 
  }
.nav3 a {   
   background-image:url(images/nav_3.gif) 
  }
.nav4 a {   
   background-image:url(images/nav_4.gif) 
  }  
.nav1 p.hover {   
   background-image:url(images/nav_1_hover.gif) 
  }
.nav2 p.hover {   
   background-image:url(images/nav_2_hover.gif) 
  }
.nav3 p.hover {   
   background-image:url(images/nav_3_hover.gif) 
  }
.nav4 p.hover {   
   background-image:url(images/nav_4_hover.gif) 
  }
```

and then here's the HTML for the menu....

```
<ul id="nav">            
  <li class="nav1"><a href=""><img src="images/nav_spacer.gif" border="0" /></a><p class="hover"></p></li>
  <li class="nav2"><a href=""><img src="images/nav_spacer.gif" border="0" /></a><p class="hover"></p></li>
  <li class="nav3"><a href=""><img src="images/nav_spacer.gif" border="0" /></a><p class="hover"></p></li>
  <li class="nav4"><a href=""><img src="images/nav_spacer.gif" border="0" /></a><p class="hover"></p></li>
</ul>​
```

I hope this is sufficient -- I'm still pretty green to Javascript/Jquery and CSS, and I can't seem to figure out why there's a buffer between my menu items.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: FYI - Your style definition for `#nav li a` has `Z-index` instead of `z-index`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which browser? I don't get any buffer in between.

Of course, I don't have your images to work with either. Perhaps there's some overflow taking place.

Try adding `clip:auto; overflow: hidden;` to your `#nav li a`.

```
#nav li a {   
   display:block;   
   width:75px;   
   height:48px;   
   margin-left:0;   
   padding-left:0;   
   z-index:20;

   clip: auto;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Also, I may be wrong about this, but as far as I remember, you'll need to set positioning in order for `z-index` to have any effect. Like: `position:relative`.

Comment: I tried this, but to no avail -- thanks for the tip on Z-index though, you're absolutely correct.

In fact, because you pointed that out, I'm going to re-structure this so that the <a> tag is a block, and have the image is described in the LI background property.

Maybe that will fix my problems.

Comment: Thanks Patrick -- the clip/overflow options didn't do anything, but you pointed something out that allowed the subsequent train of thought to lead me to the problem.

I had another list in the same #header div that had defined padding, and it was overriding the padding I set for menu.  I changed the padding to not be an attribute of #header's <li> but the specific UI's <li> and my padding issue went away.

I also changed the images to LI background properties so that the z-index (which I corrected) on the <a> tag didn't cover up the span.hover.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Correcting my original answer: You only set the left-margin, maybe you should also try setting the right margin to 0.

Comment: I thought that might be it too--it doesn't seem to matter... I tried margin/padding left 0, right 0 and just 0.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm... Try to add `display:block` for all images inside of `a` tag. This should work.